# rails spec with shoulda gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this adminuser model test and I got this results and error.What's the problem and how can I fix it
**admin_user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AdminUser do

  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:email) }
  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:password) }
  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:remember_me) }

end
```

**Result:**

```
1) AdminUser 
     Failure/Error: it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:password) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `allow_mass_assignment_of' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007f8d58d5d3a0>
     # ./spec/models/admin_user_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**AdminUser.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable

  # :timeoutable, :lockable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

#  after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }

  # def password_required?
  #   new_record? ? false : super
  # end

end
```

Comment: can u show ur model here?

Comment: are u sure is `should allow` or `should_not allow` for the password?

Comment: What about `it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:password).as(:admin) }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try...

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AdminUser do

  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:email) }
  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:password).as(:admin) }
  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:remember_me) }

end
```

Comment: did you check that `should allow` for the `password` is correct? or `should allow_not` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
require 'shoulda-matchers'
require 'shoulda/matchers/integrations/rspec'
```

at the top of your spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
require 'shoulda/integrations/rspec2'
```

this above the

```
require 'rspec/rails'
```

in **spec_helper.rb** and problem solved